# XSL: Using count to find each instance of a specific value

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to write and XSL file that finds out how many SIM cards have been bought by the same person and output that number alongside their Customer ID.

Here's an extract of the XML file with an example of the relevant tags:

```
    <sim>
        <simID>16</simID>
        <areaCode>081</areaCode>
        <number>1234582</number>
        <customerID>5</customerID>
        <yearPurchased>2008</yearPurchased>
        <monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
        <dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
    </sim>
    <customer>
        <customerID>5</customerID>
        <surname>Brown</surname>
        <firstname>Peter</firstname>
        <streetAddress>103 Main Street</streetAddress>
        <townName>Dorpborough</townName>
        <countyName>Kilkenny</countyName>
        <contractOrPrepaid>contract</contractOrPrepaid>
        <confirmedIdentity>1</confirmedIdentity>
    </customer>
```

There's multiple instances of those tags, all with the same children, within the tags `<sims>` and `<customers>`

Here's my XSL code:

```
<table rules="all">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer ID</th>
                        <th>No. of Sims Purchased</th> 
                     </tr>
                </thead> 

                <tbody>
                    <xsl:for-each select="database/customers/customer">

                        <xsl:variable name="customerIDvar" select="customerID"/>

                        <xsl:variable name="numOfSims">
                            <xsl:for-each select="database/sims/sim">
                                <xsl:value-of select="count([customerID=$customerIDvar])">
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:variable>

                        <xsl:if test="$numOfSims>1">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$customerIDvar"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$numOfSims"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>         
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong exactly, specifically it's the "numOfSims" variable I can't get to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not an answer, but shouldn't `<xsl:if test="$numOfSims>1">` be `<xsl:if test="$numOfSims &gt; 1">`?

Comment: It probably should be "&gt; 1", that would be cleaner.

Comment: @publicgk  I've recently learnt that `>` needn't be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table rules="all">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer ID</th>
                <th>No. of Sims Purchased</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="database/customers/customer">
                <xsl:variable name="customerIDvar" select="customerID"/>
                <xsl:variable name="numOfSims">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(/database/sims/sim[customerID=$customerIDvar])"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="$numOfSims>1"><tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$customerIDvar"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$numOfSims"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Assuming that your XML is something like:

```
<database>
<sims>
    <sim>
        <simID>16</simID>
        <areaCode>081</areaCode>
        <number>1234582</number>
        <customerID>5</customerID>
        <yearPurchased>2008</yearPurchased>
        <monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
        <dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
    </sim>
    <sim>
        <simID>16</simID>
        <areaCode>081</areaCode>
        <number>1234582</number>
        <customerID>5</customerID>
        <yearPurchased>2008</yearPurchased>
        <monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
        <dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
    </sim>
</sims>
<customers>
    <customer>
        <customerID>5</customerID>
        <surname>Brown</surname>
        <firstname>Peter</firstname>
        <streetAddress>103 Main Street</streetAddress>
        <townName>Dorpborough</townName>
        <countyName>Kilkenny</countyName>
        <contractOrPrepaid>contract</contractOrPrepaid>
        <confirmedIdentity>1</confirmedIdentity>
    </customer>
</customers>
</database>
```